# How to reset MPMoviePlayerController timeline to zero at movie end

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

**Streaming** 10 seconds **movie from server**, but timeline stops at 8 seconds.

There are no errors, so I would like to **reset MPMoviePlayerController timeline** left side as 00:10 and right side as 00:00 to make it look like the whole movie was played. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following - assuming that you have an instance of the MPMoviePlayerController called mp;

```
 [mp setCurrentPlaybackTime:mp.endPlaybackTime];
```

Comment: This makes video playback to jump to the beginning, but I guess it happens because the video stream is corrupted and "endPlaybackTime" location cannot be found/accessed. Still I accept this as correct answer as this is how it's supposed to work. Many thanx :)

Comment: This works:    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [aNotification object];
    mp.currentPlaybackTime = mp.duration;

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found any other video with same symphtons, so let's call this a **bug in video data or its conversion**. Case closed.

Comment: I have seen that issue several times. Actually, it is pretty common whenever a variable bitrate is used for encoding multimedia data. Take e.g. MP3 - there is no playtime information within the meta-information of an MP3, hence players usually derive the playtime from the bitrate and framesize of the first frame. Throughout the playtime of the stream, those values change, hence the initially "guessed" playtime becomes inaccurate and needs a correction. I am assuming your file/s have a missing or impossible playtime within meta-information -> player uses described method -> inaccurate playtime

Comment: Then that means all my other test videos are fine, no MP3 streaming yet at server side. Do you have any tips how to reset remaining playtime to zero after streaming is completed? I thought I saw it somewhere, but couldn't find any more!